# Simple get request

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get some data from the backend and show in the frontend but I get a syntax error..

I'm using angular 6, that's why I use pipe

My service:

```
getUsers() {
this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/users", this.options).pipe(map((response:Response) => {
  return response.json();
}));
}
```

In my frontend I call the function but

```
private users:User[];

 getUsers() {
this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
  console.log(users);
  this.users = users;
});
}
```

> **subscribe does not exist on type void**

and if I put the return in the begining of the service I get

> **void is not assignable to User[]**

Comment: in your service: write as `getUsers(): any{....}`

Comment: just remove the pipe and add httpclient instead of http(just try it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `return` before your `this._http.....`

```
getUsers() {
  return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/users", 
    this.options).pipe(map((response:Response) => {
    return response.json();
  }));
}
```

Comment: i never saw 2 returns in one function

Comment: the `return response.....` returns the result to the function above (getUsers), but this function should also return the result further up the tree for it's callers, or else `getUsers` will never return anything.

Comment: @user9729328: Just go through rxjs documentation.You got better idea what exactly that two return statement is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add return in your service

```
getUsers() {
 retrun this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/users", this.options).pipe(map((response:Response) => {
    return response.json();
  }));
  }
```